# cant print an object list in html

Tags: angularjs, html, angular, typescript

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, httpStatus: 200, httpStatusText: null, httpBodyText: "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"}

0:Object (example of object i opened to show content)
CountryInitials : "US"
Id: "101"
CountryName: "United States"
Population: 318.9
__proto__:
Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
```

this is an example from my browser that shows how im receiving the data, so its a object that contains objects, and I want to treat it in the html like its an array, and i thought it is but its not working....

this is the html:

```
<div *ngFor="#obj of myList>
        <div><b>Country ID:</b> {{obj.Id}} <b>Country Name:</b> {{obj. CountryName}}}</div>
      </div>
```

and its not working...I dont know why, i just want to present a list of the objects with country id and country name..

the EXCEPTION:

```
EXCEPTION: Error trying to diff '[object Object]' in [myList in EntityBulkCmp@32:31]
```

could someone please help me figure this out?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pipe `json` to print an object inside the template: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/JsonPipe-pipe.html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'json-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Without JSON pipe:</p>
    <pre>{{object}}</pre>
    <p>With JSON pipe:</p>
    <pre>{{object | json}}</pre>
  </div>`
})
export class JsonPipeComponent {
  object: Object = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux', nested: {xyz: 3, numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception says items in myList are not unique. Probably you have some repeated elements.

Angular needs to keep track of which item it is enumerating.

Use trackBy option, find the syntax below

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

refer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html for complete usage of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `key` and `value` to print the json format...
In which `key` is 0, 1, etc (as in your case) and `value` is object (as in your case)...